# File Handling Support in Charm++

Tags: charm++

Does Charm++ support File Handling? I mean can we perform file operation(read/write) in Charm++? If yes, please give an simple example of File Handling for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do any kind of file I/O in Charm++, though you may have to take care to properly synchronize parallel file accesses (if doing parallel I/O, say, from all elements of a chare array). The options for doing I/O are essentially:

1) Do I/O from a dedicated object. You can reduce and broadcast data to and from that object, and use any serial I/O method you want. Since Charm++ is built-on a message-driven execution paradigm, the I/O object will only be scheduled when it actually has work to do.

2) Do I/O from all objects. You can either use Charm++'s built-in asynchronous parallel I/O library "CkIO" directly from chare array elements, or you can use MPI-IO, HDF5, or whatever other parallel I/O library you want. To do the latter, you will want to use Charm++'s MPI interoperability features and do the I/O from a Charm++ "Group" or "Node Group" so that there is one I/O actor per PE or node.

Of course you can also do I/O from a subset of all objects, and you have the choice of using a single global file or one file per PE/node.

To see an example of CkIO's usage, have a look at tests/charm++/io/ in the Charm++ source. An example of MPI interop is in examples/charm++/mpi-coexist/.